# Why does callable type hinting call?

Tags: php

I give strings like 'myproject\module\Controller::Action' to one of the method, which must make sure that specified method exists and is public. The simplest and most logical way is to use type hinting:

```
protected doSomething(callable $method, ...)
{
   ...
}
```

But! This gives me:

> Deprecated: Non-static method
>   myproject\module\Controller::Action() should not be
>   called statically in path_to_script: line where function is defined

What a hell?? Why does type hinting tries to call method when it must only to check if it's callable? How to use such type hinting without errors?

Using PHP 7.0.2 with strict types and error_reporting(PHP_INT_MAX).

Comment: What version of PHP did this code last work on?

Comment: Type hinting has nothing to do with this. What really causes this error is `strict standards` which doesn't allow to call not static method statically.

Comment: Well... How can I mute Deprecated error for this statement only?